# Extruding Vertices Is Moving the Original Vertices

Tags: vertex-groups, extrude

I've been following the BlenderGuru donut tutorial and was extruding these two vertices but it somehow moves the original vertices as I do so. Anyone know how I can extrude these vertices without moving the originals? I tried switching off proportional editing and that doesn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*'On cage'* option is on for the subdivision modifier.

Set it off.

[image]

This option shows vertex positions as if they were already modified by the modifier.

Comment: Ah Brilliant! I must have toggled that on accidentally. Thanks!